# Automaticly run xinit from rc.local as different user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm working on some tuning of my raspberry. So I decided that midori should start automaticly after autologin.
With startx it works without problems, but X is still to ressource hungry. So I'll start midori with xinit and matchbox.

As test, I use as user "pi" this command "xinit ./home/pi/startmidori.sh" and it works.
So I'll put this into my rc.local file.

There is the command "su -l pi -c xinit ./home/pi/startmidori.sh", this doesn't work. I don't know why, but xinit exit immediately after starting.

How can I solve this? In guides I find this kind of solution, but for it doesn't work. I tryed to run it as root but it doesn't work, too. I've no idea why.

Comment: This is likely off topic for Stack Overflow, you might be able to get help at [Super User](http://superuser.com)

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry, thank you for giving me this hint. I posted it on SU [link](http://superuser.com/questions/800994/automaticly-run-xinit-from-rc-local-as-different-user)

Answer (score -1):

Check this for more information: [Running X](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/XWindow-User-HOWTO/runningx.html) from The X Window User HOWTO
In general you always need a wrapper and you must run X with root, since it needs raw access to hardware devices.

So I suggest you to install lightweight display manager like LightDM if possible it has almost no footprint and then easy you can set it up to [auto login](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM#Enabling_autologin) with desired user and run desired window manager like matchbox in your case.